# MS AdventureWorks dbo.ufnGetProductListPrice

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I'm studing the Ms SQL AdventureWorks 2014, to model an internal dbase for our company

I usually work on  Postgres, and I'm trying to "understand" Ms SQL stored procedures... :-)) BUT ....

The store Procedure [dbo.ufnGetProductListPrice  ] SEEMS STRANGE to me.
the SQL code is found here:
(https://dataedo.com/samples/html/AdventureWorks/doc/AdventureWorks_2/functions/dbo_ufnGetProductListPrice_116.html)

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetProductListPrice](@ProductID [int], @OrderDate [datetime])
RETURNS [money] 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ListPrice money;

    SELECT @ListPrice = plph.[ListPrice] 
    FROM [Production].[Product] p 
        INNER JOIN [Production].[ProductListPriceHistory] plph 
        ON p.[ProductID] = plph.[ProductID] 
            AND p.[ProductID] = @ProductID 
            AND @OrderDate BETWEEN plph.[StartDate] AND COALESCE(plph.[EndDate], CONVERT(datetime, '99991231', 112)); -- Make sure we get all the prices!

    RETURN @ListPrice;
END;
```

The function is making use of the following two tables:

- [Production.Product] (https://dataedo.com/samples/html/AdventureWorks/doc/AdventureWorks_2/tables/Production_Product_153.html)
- [Production.ProductListPriceHistory] - (https://dataedo.com/samples/html/AdventureWorks/doc/AdventureWorks_2/tables/Production_ProductListPriceHistory_159.html)

In particular my doubts are:

1. the function is getting the  parameter @ProductID.
   The same @ProductID is used as the primary key of the Production.Product AND as part of the primary key for the table Production.ProductListPriceHistory
   so is seems of no help making a join on  Product.[ProductID] = ProductListPriceHistory.[ProductID]
   when we can test the ProductID directly on the ProductListPriceHistory.[ProductID]
   **Why to create such a join ? Seems of no help...**
2. The given @Orderdate datetime received as second parameter, is checked in the JOIN against the following condition

AND @OrderDate BETWEEN plph.[StartDate] AND COALESCE(plph.[EndDate], CONVERT(datetime, '99991231', 112)); -- Make sure we get all the prices!

BUT, if we are calling the store procedure for @Orderdate = 1/1/2022,

- considering that [EndDate] could be NULL,
- and we could have in ProductListPriceHistory.StartDate  two records with our @ProductID, the first with StartDate=1/1/2020 and the second StartDate=1/1/2021,

such "BETWEEN" condition should match both of them, when obviously we would expect the last one ....
**is it a bug ?**

Comment: This learning "resource" is flawed on several levels, I would disregard it completely. I also would *not* model anything on AdventureWorks!

Answer (score 3):

You are right, there are a number of serious flaws in this code, and I would recommend finding better tutorials instead.

I've noted comments on each flaw

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnGetProductListPrice](@ProductID [int], @OrderDate [datetime])
RETURNS [money]   -- money is a bad data type due to rounding problems, decimal should be used
                  -- scalar UDFs are very slow, this should be a inline Table Valued Function
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ListPrice money;

    SELECT @ListPrice = plph.[ListPrice]    -- as you point out, there should be some kind of aggregation
    FROM [Production].[Product] p           -- as you point out: join is unnecessary
        INNER JOIN [Production].[ProductListPriceHistory] plph 
        ON p.[ProductID] = plph.[ProductID] 
            AND p.[ProductID] = @ProductID 
                           -- BETWEEN should never be used on dates, use ">= AND <"
            AND @OrderDate BETWEEN plph.[StartDate] AND COALESCE(plph.[EndDate], CONVERT(datetime, '99991231', 112));   -- ISNULL is better for performance than COALESCE

    RETURN @ListPrice;
END;
```

A better function would be this

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetProductListPrice (
  @ProductID int,
  @OrderDate datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT TOP (1)
  plph.ListPrice
FROM Production.ProductListPriceHistory plph 
WHERE plph.ProductID = @ProductID 
  AND @OrderDate >= plph.StartDate
  AND @OrderDate < ISNULL(plph.EndDate, CONVERT(datetime, '99991231', 112))
ORDER BY
  plph.StartDate DESC;
```

Assuming it's possible for there to be multiple active prices (I don't think it's possible in AdventureWorks), then you also need `TOP (1)` and `ORDER BY plph.StartDate DESC`. If this is not possible then you can leave that out.

---

Instead of doing this with a scalar UDF

```sql
SELECT p.*, dbo.ufnGetProductListPrice(p.ProductId, GETDATE())
FROM Production.Product p;
```

You use an `APPLY` for a TVF

```sql
SELECT p.*, plp.*
FROM Production.Product p
OUTER APPLY dbo.ufnGetProductListPrice(p.ProductId, GETDATE()) plp;
```

An `OUTER APPLY` works like a `LEFT JOIN`, which means you get `NULL` if there are no rows.

Comment: Thansk Charlieface.
I believe it should return a valid price or null/zero if product didn't exist at that date.
HOW to fix the code "below" (I had to make a new comment) in case  no listPrice is available for the given OrderDate ?

Comment: Just use `OUTER APPLY` then, along with a `TOP 1`

Answer (score 0):

@Charlieface
Thanks for your reply. One more note on the function ufnGetProductStandardCost

AdventureWorks is storing historical Retailprices and CostPrices, to let you found the price (list, cost) of a certain product at a certain time. This is why I'm interested in this part of the database

It even offers a "dual" function for Cost prices ufnGetProductStandardCost
https://dataedo.com/samples/html/AdventureWorks/doc/AdventureWorks_2/functions/dbo_ufnGetProductStandardCost_117.html
with the same errors :-(

I think that the idea of ufnGetProductListPrice(ProductID, OrderDate), is to report a SINGLE price or Null if at that given time the price did not exist.
NOT a table or listrow.

Let's just recall the case I supposed before

- search OrderDate 1/1/2022
- one record with StartDate=1/1/2020 , EndDate=null
- one record with StartDate=1/1/2021 , EndDate=null

One idea for such function would be to:

- use a subquery to find the MAX() StardDate<@OrderDate for the given @ProductId
- use such StartDate to get the correspondig ListPrice in the external query
  or give back NULL if we have NO StartDate ListPrice before @OrderDate  (e.g @OrderDate=1/1/2019)

What do you think about this query ? Any improvement ?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetProductListPrice (
  @ProductID int,
  @OrderDate datetime
)
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @ListPrice money;

SELECT @ListPrice= plph.ListPrice
FROM Production.ProductListPriceHistory plph 
WHERE plph.ProductID = @ProductID 
  AND plhp.StartDate = (
        SELECT MAX(StardDate)
        FROM Production.ProductListPriceHistory plph1
        WHERE plph1.ProductID = @ProductID
            AND plhp1.StartDate <=  @OrderDate)         
RETURN @ListPrice;
END;
```

Comment: No more efficient to just use `TOP 1`, also this fails if there are two rows with the exact same `StartDate`. Also scalar UDFs are slow as mentioned